# Adding WHERE to an AS statement in SQL

Tags: sql

Is it possible to add a WHERE statement to an AS? When i run sql like this is always fails. I just need some kind of example, and I couldn't find anything at stack from my searching.

```
SELECT *, 
COUNT(my_other_table.id) as 'c_others' WHERE my_other_table.active = 1
LEFT JOIN my_other_table on my_accounts.id = my_other_table.account_connection
FROM my_accounts
ORDER BY my_accounts.name
```

Note how I added WHERE my_other_table.active = 1, that's where i'm breaking everything

I'm not 100% sure how AS statements work, usually I don't do anything complex with them. But now that I need to, i can't figure it out

Comment: There is a set structure for sql and must be adhered to or the system doesn't know what your doing @Till answer is the best, see the syntax and particular structure ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `WHERE` clause has to be at the end of the table list, before the optional `ORDER BY`. Look at this definition of the structure a SELECT statement has to adhere to:

```
SELECT 
[ DISTINCT | ALL ] 
  <select list>
  FROM <table reference list>
[ <where clause> ]             <-- THIS IS THE INTERESTING PART
[ <group by clause> ]
[ <having clause> ]
[ UNION [ALL] <query specification> ]
[ <order by clause> ]
```

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(my_other_table.id) AS c_others
FROM my_accounts
LEFT JOIN my_other_table ON my_accounts.id = my_other_table.account_connection
WHERE my_other_table.active = 1
ORDER BY my_accounts.name
```

You also could add the condition to your `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(my_other_table.id) AS c_others
FROM my_accounts
JOIN my_other_table ON 
   my_accounts.id = my_other_table.account_connection
   AND my_other_table.active = 1
ORDER BY my_accounts.name
```

The `AS` statement does nothing else than specify an alias name for a selected field. This can be useful when a fieldname is too long, you want to define a name for a function call (e.g. `COUNT(column) AS counter`, just as you used it) or to avoid name clashes when you join tables with similar column names. You can also use `AS` to specify an alias for a *table name* to avoid having to type it more than once.

**Edit:**

As noted in the comments by HamletHakobyan: `COUNT` is an aggregation function that might require you to use a `GROUP BY` clause on the other fields selected in your statement. So you need to expand the `*` into the actual fieldnames and do it like this:

```
SELECT
   my_accounts.name, 
   my_accounts.firstname, 
   COUNT(my_other_table.id) AS c_others
FROM my_accounts
JOIN my_other_table ON 
   my_accounts.id = my_other_table.account_connection
   AND my_other_table.active = 1
GROUP BY my_accounts.name, my_accounts.firstname
ORDER BY my_accounts.name
```

Comment: If you in SQL Server you can't do this without grouping.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan True. I'll add that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `WHERE` clause as:

```
SELECT *, 
    COUNT(my_other_table.id) as 'c_others'
FROM my_accounts
    LEFT JOIN my_other_table
        ON my_accounts.id = my_other_table.account_connection
WHERE my_other_table.active = 1
GROUP BY <list all necessary fields>
ORDER BY my_accounts.name
```

or,if you want to get selective count of elements use this

```
SELECT <list all necessary fields>, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN my_other_table.active = 1 THEN my_other_table.id END) as 'c_others'
FROM my_accounts
    LEFT JOIN my_other_table
        ON my_accounts.id = my_other_table.account_connection
GROUP BY <list all necessary fields>
ORDER BY my_accounts.name
```

Answer (score 0):

`AS` merely introduces a new *name* for an object (column, table, etc). As such, applying a `WHERE` to it doesn't make sense (since the name of the, in this instance, column) is fixed for the entire result set.

At a guess, you actually want to modify the `COUNT`, so that you're only counting those rows where `active` is 1:

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(CASE WHEN my_other_table.active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'c_others'
LEFT JOIN my_other_table on my_accounts.id = my_other_table.account_connection
FROM my_accounts
ORDER BY my_accounts.name
```

Answer (score 0):

AS is just a keyword to give a name to column. Which is handy in complex column definitions. The name will work only in query result, but not within query - you cannot reference it back in the same query. You'll have to use sub-query then.

WHERE (as well as other keywords) have their place in Query as Till Helge have had written.